# React pass specific state to the Modal component on click

Tags: reactjs

Trying to pass `state` to Modal Component onClick. Currently it passes all the states when using following code:

my state:

```
this.state = {
            test: '',
            test2: '',
            modalIsOpen: false,

            ...

            testData: ''
        }
```

on click:

```
openModal(e) {
    console.log(e)
    this.setState({ testData: e });
}
```

modal component:

```
<Modal
  isOpen={this.state.modalIsOpen}
  onRequestClose={this.closeModal}
  {...this.state}
>
  <button onClick={this.closeModal}>close</button>
  <div>I am a modal</div>
</Modal>
```

I have tried `{...this.state.testData}` but throws error. How can I pass just `testData` state to the component is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what you are talking about...

```
<Modal
  isOpen={this.state.modalIsOpen}
  onRequestClose={this.closeModal}
  testData={this.state.testData}
>
```